# how to discard a nested object in Grails web flow

Tags: hibernate, grails, spring-webflow

I am using Grails web flow. I have two domain classes ProducutItem and Product. Product Item has a field called product of type Product.

I use productItem.product to reference the product. Since I am using web Flow and I dont want to make these class serializable i have to discard them after the use. But I am not able to figure out how to discard the nested product Object. I have tried **productItem.disacrd()** or **productItem.product.discard()** but they dont work

Answer (score 0):

Discarding an object will only disconnect them from the hibernate session. That will not make them Serializable.

If you wish to avoid serializing the product object, you can try this:

```
productItem.discard()
productItem.product=null
```

Comment: Disconnecting the product object from hibernate session is exactly what I need so that there is no need to serialize product domain. Using productItem.product=null in not working..

Comment: Do you mean that the serialization mechanism does not serialize an object if it is not connected to a hibernate session? What about Command objects, or simple strings that you have in your web flow? Do you mean that these objects will not be serialized either?